# Plot a vector valued function of two variables using color density

Tags: plotting, color

I have a vector (3D) valued function of two variables.  I want to visualize it as a density plot, using R,G,B color values to display the value at the point (x,y).
I've come up with a couple of attempts, neither satisfactory.  One is to use a Raster, but that doesn't adapt to the function and so needs too many function evaluations.  My other solution is to make three contour plots and combine them, but  to do that I needed to use Opacity and then the range of colors is muted.

Here's an example, with a simple function:

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y, x + y}
Table[
   DensityPlot[f[x, y][[i]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
               ColorFunction -> (ReplacePart[RGBColor[0,0,0], i -> #] &)],
   {i, 3}]
Show[Table[
   DensityPlot[f[x, y][[i]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
         ColorFunction -> ({Opacity[1/3], ReplacePart[RGBColor[0,0,0], i -> #]} &)],
   {i, 3}]]
```

The first table shows three DensityPlots with the RGB components I want, which look like this:

[image: rgb component images]

The Show combines them into one. But what I really want to do is **add** the color values in the three plots, and Show with Opacity averages them, giving a murky image.  In this example, I want white in the upper right, black in the lower left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#, #2, # + #2] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

or maybe, as Rasher has suggested:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Rescale[#, {-1, 1}] & /@ RGBColor[#, #2, # + #2] &),    
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Prepending`Rescale[#, {-1, 1}] & /@` to `RGBColor` prettifies this nicely. +1

Comment: @rasher well, I'm not sure what OP wants :) You are probably right, I was thinking about the same but via `{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ..., ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#, #2, (# + #2)/2] &` :). Or similar, because it is not the same :P

Comment: Both of these seem like useful general techniques, and in fact the first one works well for me since the actual function I'm dealing with is already scaled to be in [0,1].For a general function `f`, the `Rescale` would need to be a bit fancier to adapt to what might be different ranges for the three coordinates of `f`.