# shade plane with a color function color(x,y)

Tags: plotting, color

I am making a RGB color function which assigns an RGB color to each point in the plane. To check if it does what I think it should do (i.e. debugging it), it is helpful to be able to plot the function to see how the problematic areas are arising. How can I plot this function? i.e. is there something along the lines of

```
Plot[RGB[f[x,y],g[x,y],h[x,y]],{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

Comment: closely related: [50461](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50461/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cf = Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Mean@{x, y}]];
RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ColorFunction -> cf];
```

[image]

Comment: wait - if you change the plot range, nothing happens - what's going on?

Comment: Oh it just needs to be rescaled. `ColorData` domains are {0,1}

Comment: and there's no other way around it? - hold on - this has the same problem, and doesn't use ColorData: 

cf = Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[x, y, 0]];

Comment: `RGBColor` also takes values in the domain {0,1}. If you have your domain you can just divide by a constant to get the values in that range.